# Use of variable in 'for' loop is not recognized in Go

Tags: for-loop, go, compiler-errors, unused-variables

I'm developing in Go and I run the following *for* loop:

```
// Define Initial Value
i := 0

for {
    // Get random data based on iteration
    data, i := GiveRandomData(i)

    // Save to database
    response, err := SaveToDatabase(data)

    if err != nil { log.Fatal(err) }
    fmt.Println(response)
}
```

However, when compiling this program, I get the following error:

> .\main.go:26: i declared and not used

The Go compiler doesn't seem to recognise that the `i` variable is given back to the function in the next loop. Inside this function, the `I` variable changes value.

What should I do to get rid of this compilation error or to let Go understand that this variable is *not* unused, but used in the next iteration of this endless *for* loop?

Answer (score 9):

> The Go compiler doesn't seem to recognise that the `i` variable is given back to the function in the next loop. Inside this function, the `I` variable changes value.

No, `i` does not change value; `:=` declares a new `i`. (Go allows you to do this because `data` is also new.) To assign to it instead, you’ll need to declare `data` separately:

```
var data RandomDataType
data, i = GiveRandomData(i)
```

Or give the new `i` a temporary name:

```
data, next := GiveRandomData(i)
i = next
```