# Infinite 'for' loop in Go

Tags: loops, go

I'm new to Go, but I would expect not to have issues with something as basic as this.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    s := make([]int, 0)
    s = append(s, 1)
    for len(s) != 0 {
        j := len(s) - 1
        top, s := s[j], s[:j]
        fmt.Printf("top = %+v\n", top)
        fmt.Printf("s = %+v\n", s)
        fmt.Printf("len(s) = %+v\n", len(s))
    }
}
```

This command doesn't exit. It just prints

```
len(s) = 0
top = 1
s = []
len(s) = 0
top = 1
s = []
len(s) = ^C
```

I find this stunning; what am I doing wrong? Syntactically, based on https://tour.golang.org/flowcontrol/3, everything seems OK.

Comment: Going off question , if you ever want to break infinite loop one way is using "os.exit(0)" . May it help users who are new to Golang.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use `:=`, you declare new variables. An `s` is created inside the loop unrelated to the `s` outside it. Assign instead:

```
for len(s) != 0 {
    j := len(s) - 1
    var top int
    top, s = s[j], s[:j]
    fmt.Printf("top = %+v\n", top)
    fmt.Printf("s = %+v\n", s)
    fmt.Printf("len(s) = %+v\n", len(s))
}
```

Comment: (at the time of this writing, this is [1/3 of my answers about Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45137897/use-of-variable-in-for-loop-not-recognized-in-golang/45138077#45138077))

Comment: @YvetteColomb: I knew it was a duplicate but wanted to give an explanation with a more complete code example.

Comment: I was under the impression that `:=` was smart enough to not redeclare variables already in scope in the case of a tuple where one entry is already in scope. Apparently I was wrong.